# как получить связанные данные из другой pivot таблицы (Laravel)?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Как мне получить цвета для материала из **pivot** таблицы, через модель товара?

**В модели Product:**

```
 public function material(){
     return $this->belongsToMany('App\Shop\ProductMaterial', 'pivot_products_mat_top', 
     'product_id', 'product_material_id');
 }
```

Так же есть такие таблицы:

(pivot, без модели) **material_color:** | product_color_id | product_color_id |

(с моделью) **product_colors:** | id | name | image |

**в модели App\Shop\ProductMaterial:**

```
  public function colors(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Shop\ProductColor', 'material_color', 
    'product_material_id', 'product_color_id');
  }
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в функции `materaial()` в модели `product` подцепить цвета к материалу и возможно ли это? Изучаю **Laravel 7**, впервые делаю на нем проект, в документации по связям (relationships) так и не  разобрался как решить эту задачу.

Comment: в контроллере `$product->material()->get();` но думаю это и так понятно

Answer (score 0):

Решил задачу следующим образом. Но мне кажется немного колхоз. Напишите в комментах, может есть какая-то встроенная ф-я самой лары?

**App\Product** (model)

```
public function material($table_ending){
$materials = $this->belongsToMany('App\Shop\ProductMaterial', 
 'pivot_products_mat_'.$table_ending,  'product_id', 'product_material_id')->get();

foreach($materials as $k=>$mat){
  $colors = ProductMaterial::find($mat->id);
  $materials[$k]['colors'] = $colors->colors()->get();
}

  return $materials;
}
```